# Бесконечный цикл, как продолжить выполнение кода и оставить цикл в бекграунде?

Tags: php

Есть страница сайта с HTML и PHP кодом. В PHP подключаюсь к сокету и бесконечно ожидаю и считываю входящие данные (текстовый чат с другого сайта), естественно, когда запускается бесконечный цикл прогрузка страницы останавливается и никаких действий совершать нельзя. Как запустить этот цикл на заднем фоне, что бы не мешал работать с сайтом?

Comment: не совсем понятно что происходит у тебя на сайте)) что значит останавливается прогрузка страницы?

Comment: Очереди использовать.

Comment: Никак. Это невозможно. Скрипты php могут выполняться определенное время, обычно это 30 секунд. Но вы можете запускать скрипт снова и снова - или кроном, или постоянной перезагрузкой страницы(фрейма), или через аякс запросы, в зависимости от того, как у вас все организовано.